# Web content retrived by using file_get_contents() and curl has improper latin characters

Tags: php, curl, encoding, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Either by using file_get_contents() or curl functions, output is wrong, to be specific, east-european **č** and **ć** latin characters is always replaced by nasty characters, **šđž** sometimes, depends if I'm trying something with changing internal encoding of PHP - it only get worse.

Yes, I've read similar topics, but with following these instructions, things get worse.

Does anyone have solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is with *displaying* the data, not with reading it. Stop reading "instructions" and devote some time to learning about text encodings.

Comment: Sorry, but this is *way* too hazy to give any kind of meaningful answer. You'll have to add much more detail. I have a link that may help you though

Comment: @Jon actually, it is problem with reading, as I think... I've tried file_put_contents with retrived data, problem remains

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @deceze,thanks, that article looks like serious tut.

Comment: use this in beginning of the script `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you try to display the data with wrong encoding, if the data your accessing with file_get_contents/curl is a remote html page, read the Content-Type from header or  tag and convert the encoding using [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)